# Water rising in my second sump pit but not the first

Tags: plumbing, sump-pump

We have lived in our home for over 3 years. We have 2 sump pits, each with a pump. The second pit is operated with a battery back up in case of power failures. Recently, we have found that the back up pump is going off every 3 hours or so. The primary operates only sporadically. I know we have water entering the pits normally during periods of no rain due to the water table but I am confused why this would suddenly start happening in the second pit.

Any insights?

Answer (score -1):

water under a foundation is entirely unpredictable.  its governed by rainfall, tmemperature, soil moisture level, slope, etc.  there is absolutely no reason to worry if the pumps are running properly and doing there job, as there is no way to solve the problem (if there is indeed one) without just randomly trying different changes to any of the above.  this is all predicated on the fact that both pumps have been checked and are working fine.  if not, start there.

Comment: Pumps are working fine. I did a manual test by pumping in water as well. But I am concerned that two pits practically 6 inches apart has this significantly different behavior.

Comment: there is absolutely no way to tell how anything is plumbed, or how the foundation is drained without x-raying or demolishing it all.  just leave it be.  if the pumps are draining the water, the system is working as its supposed to.  if it ain't broke, don't fix it